# What Israeli laws are there concerning the word "Nazi"

Tags: freedom-of-speech, slander

The internet has numerous reports, which are often vague, about laws proposed or existing in Israel regulating use of the word "Nazi."

Some apparently are not just about that word but are about any offensive references or displays invoking the German National Socialist Workers Party. Of course such laws exist in many countries.   Other sites online seem to describe laws specifically about the word "Nazi," and those are the ones I'd like to know about.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [summary](https://www.knesset.gov.il/spokesman/eng/PR_eng.asp?PRID=11089) of the Protection of Symbols Bill on the Knesset website (it passed a preliminary reading: it has to pass three more readings). There has not apparently been any action since.